# how would I style navigation with hr on the same line

Tags: css, navigation, nav

Ok so below is a representation and description of what I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to add a navigation on the same line but after an hr tag so that the outcome is something like this...

----------------------------------------------------------------------------- Home  Services  Facilities  About  Contact

The best I can do shows one of the nav links but the others are not rendered

HTML

---

```
    <ul>

      <li class="active"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>

      <li><a href="index.php">SERVICES</a></li>

      <li><a href="index.php">FACILITIES</a></li>

      <li><a href="index.php">WITH US</a></li>

      <li><a href="index.php">CONTACT</a></li>

     </ul>

  </div>
```

css

```
body {
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #FFF;
}
.divider {
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
}

.divider hr {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.divider ul {
  float: right;
}
.divider li {
  float: left;
}
.divider a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #68C5DE;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 2px 20px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulStarkey/2mgmbbk4/)

I think I may have over or under complicated things but this has left me scratching my head for 4 hours now.

Is this possible to achieve this in a way that still enables percentiles on the hr?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed all links on top of each other with

`.divider a {
    position: absolute;
}`

Comment: "*[It] is usual practice to use tags for what they're used for*" - you might want to clarify your meaning, I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Thanks Lukadante3, this was an over site on my part. All sorted now. Not sure what you meant by "you shouldn't use <hr> tag for something like this. it is good practice to use tags for what they're used for."

Answer (score 0):

If the background isn't an issue then you can use a pseudo element :before to create the line then have the list items overlap it with a white background color to hide it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">FACILITIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">WITH US</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.nav-wrapper { margin-top: 50px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
.navigation {
  float: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation:before {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    width: 100%;
}
.navigation li {
  background-color: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mgmbbk4/2/)

Comment: Thanks Lee, This would have solved the problem but I should have mentioned that the hr has a gradient fade at both ends so I cant really use this method.